# webgl I want to detect if TRIANGLE_FAN is possible

Tags: internet-explorer, webgl

`TRIANGLE_FAN` is not supported by IE, but it's supported by e.g. Chrome. I would like to detect whether the browser used supports `TRIANGLE_FAN` or not. Is it possible to get this information from rendering context ?

Thanks,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
All uppercase variables from the context are constants.

```
var gl = myCanvas.getContext("webgl");

if( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN != undefined )
    // hurray!
else
    // this is IE
```

You could also try retrieve browser's name through something like `navigator.appName`, with or without the webGL.

Comment: Well, none of the solution works, unfortunately.
navigator.appName in IE 11 gives "Netscape"...